# How many Pages do a certain number of Bytes amount to?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmu

Given a system supports a certain page-size of X-KB (Power of 2), and I have a certain number of bytes Y-Bytes(May or May not be a multiple of X). Is there a macro that will give me a "ceil" of the number of pages that would amount to Y-Bytes ?

Thanks,
vj

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is such a macro. But you can easily write your own using the asm/page.h PAGE_SIZE and PAGE_SHIFT definitions.

```
NUM_PAGES(y) ((y + PAGE_SIZE - 1) >> PAGE_SHIFT)
```

or

```
NUM_PAGES(y) ((y + PAGE_SIZE - 1) / PAGE_SIZE)
```

Comment: Perhaps `DIV_ROUND_UP(y, PAGE_SIZE)`